# Error while generating APK react-native

Tags: react-native

when i try to generate my apk it gave me this error 
i tried many solutions and did'nt work out

after i run command:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

the error is:

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: appfolder\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\release\index.andro
id.bundle
 
Don't know which android drawable suffix to use for asset: {"__packager_asset":true,"fileSystemLocation":"appfolder\\src\\public\\images\\icons","httpServerLocation":"/assets/src/public/images/icons","width":12,"height":10,"scales":
[1,2,3,4,5],"files":["appfolder\\src\\public\\images\\icons\\twitter@1x.png","appfolder\\src\\public\\images\\icons\\twitter@2x.png","appfolder\\src\\public\\images
\\icons\\twitter@3x.png","appfolder\\src\\public\\images\\icons\\twitter@4x.png","appfolder\\src\\public\\images\\icons\\twitter@5x.png"],"hash":"aa736287bfea056b34205edd2839d8cc","name":"twitter","
type":"png"}

 
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
 
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: According to [RN](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html) you can't use @4x or @5x, which is why it's not a supported tag as it doesn't map to Android sizes. I assume you're trying to `require` which is where the problem will arise when building. Remove the ones that are above '@3x' and you should be ok. Also, read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) which should help if you need to provide Android specific sizes.

Comment: @G0dsquad thank you so much 
i did what u told me 
i set the assets to 
@1x
@1.5x
@2x
@3x
@4x
and it builds successfully
i put the apk on my phone i installed it after i try to open it
it crashs away
`unfortunately, App has stopped`

Comment: and after that i deleted files @1.5 and @4 and still the same problem
and in debug install works fine :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error was in assets: i removed @5x
special thanks to @G0dsquad for his comment